# Problem with showing images on exporting HTML to pdf in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, css, dinktopdf

I want to export the database to pdf in the table for each user including their images. the problem is that it shows specific images with height and width. for example, a pic with 359x214 is shown perfectly, But one with 264x364 can't be shown. I even resized the second one to be exactly the same size as the first one but still doesn't work! They both are JPEG-type pictures. I even increased the height of the row in which the picture is to be shown but still failed. I use DinkToPdf to convert HTML to pdf

```
public IActionResult CreatePdf()
        {
            var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
            {
                ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
                DocumentTitle = "Users_Report"

            };
            var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
            {
                PagesCount = true,
                HtmlContent = GetHTMLString(),
                WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8",UserStyleSheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Assets", "Style.css"), LoadImages = true },
                HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
                FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "User" }
            };
            var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
                Objects = { objectSettings }
            };
            var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);
            return File(file, "application/pdf", "Users.pdf");

        }
        public string GetHTMLString()
        {
            var users = _dbContext.Users.ToList();
            var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                var picAddress = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/image/", user.ImageName);
                sb.Append(@"
                        <html dir='rtl' lang='fa-IR'>
                            <head>
                            </head>
                            <body dir='rtl'>");

                sb.AppendFormat(@"<table align ='center'>
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td></td>
                                          <td><img src={0} asp-append-version='true' width='110px' height='130px' /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{1}</td>
                                          <td>{2}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{3}</td>
                                          <td>{4}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{5}</td>
                                          <td>{6}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{7}</td>
                                          <td>{8}</td>
                                        </tr>", picAddress, user.FullName, user.FatherName, user.IdCardNumber,
                                        user.DateOfBirth, user.MaritalStatus, user.MilitaryServiceStatus, user.CallNumber, user.Address);
                sb.Append(@"
                                </table>
                            </body>
                        </html>");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    public IActionResult Complete()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Here is the Style.css file

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin:5px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

th, td {
    width:50%;   
}
```